# using gregorian calendar as a time stamp

Tags: java, constructor, gregorian-calendar

I have a project with an email class, as shown below

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Email /*implements serializbale*/{

private String to;
private String cc;
private String bcc;
private String subject;
private String body;
private GregorianCalendar timestamp;    //time that email was created

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();


public Email(String to, String cc, String bcc, String subject, String body, GregorianCalendar timestamp) {
    super();
    this.to = to;
    this.cc = cc;
    this.bcc = bcc;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.body = body;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
```

I was thinking that I wouldn't even need a timestamp parameter in the constructor. I want to just set timestamp to the current time whenever that contractor is called for an email object. Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: You should be running JDK and using the new Java time classes.  LocalDateTime makes this trivial.

Comment: I am required to use the Gregorian calendar for this

Comment: I'd talk to someone about that.  Why use a Java 1.0 class that has been completely supplanted by its JDK 8 package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use as below to get current time

```
LocalDateTime currentTime;
public Email(String to, String cc, String bcc, String subject, String body) {
super();
this.to = to;
this.cc = cc;
this.bcc = bcc;
this.subject = subject;
this.body = body;
this.currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Comment: See?  That's JDK 8 LocalDateTime.  20 years of experience improving over GregorianCalendar.